# xml to java bean conversion using apache xml-beans-2.5.0

Tags: xml, xsd, xmlbeans

Iam trying to generate java beans using jdk 1.5 and xml-beans-2.5.0, iam able to generate the jar, but when i try to use the generated type using
final ActionsDocument actionsDoc = ActionsDocument.Factory.parse(inputStream);
it gives me error The type javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.
But if i use jdk 1.6, it works fine. I need to make it work for 1.5.

Answer (score 0):

When using JDK 1.5 you need the jsr173_1.0_api.jar on the classpath.